# Service in Angular 2 not returing values to the html component

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 2.  I have a service hosted in my local machine.  The service works fine.  But when I am about to retrieve the data from a service in my Angular 2.  As show below: The data was successfully retrieved and was log in the my console.  But when I am about to show the values in my view.  The "this.myPurchaseItems" is empty.  Why is that? please help. thanks

```
calling file......
this._service.getMyPracticeTest(this.uid).subscribe(data => {  this.myPurchaseItems = data }); 
------------------------------------------------------

service.ts file..... 
getMyPracticeTest(uid: string){
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:49753/RestServiceImpl.svc/getMyPracticeTest/' + uid)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(data => console.log("GetMyPracticeTest" + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
------------------------------------------------------

 <table class="table">
      <tr><th>ID</th></tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let data of myPurchaseItems">
          <td>{{data.Purchase_ID}}</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

SOLUTION to the problem.

```
getMyPracticeTest(uid: string){
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:49753/RestServiceImpl.svc/getMyPracticeTest/' + uid)
    .map(data => {
        data.json();
        // the console.log(...) line prevents your code from working 
        // either remove it or add the line below (return ...)
        console.log("I CAN SEE DATA HERE: ", data.json());
        return data.json();
}
```

Comment: Assuming the 3rd file is the view for the first file, you just have a name mismatch with "myPurchaseItems" and "myTestData"

Comment: typo error.  it's myPurchaseItems.

Comment: If your data is an array then it should work fine in theory. Did you change the ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush by any chance? If not, everything should work according to your example. Hard to comment any further without a plunkr.

Comment: Can you post code of you component? also how do you declare myPurchaseItems

Comment: also can you attach screen what is console printing?

Comment: Found a solution to this one.  I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have much to go on here but I recently had trouble with my `*ngFor` bindings calling it up the way you are.  Instead try this

```
<tr *ngFor="let Purchase_ID of myPurchaseItems.data">
    <td>{{Purchase_ID}}</td>
</tr>
```

that did it for me, if this doesn't work, post the code to your component and service so we can have a better look at what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before, the issue was change detection not being run.

Can you try this, inside your component constructor

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

Inside your completion block

```
this._service.getMyPracticeTest(this.uid).subscribe(data => 
 {  
   this.myPurchaseItems = data;  
   this.cdRef.detectChanges();
 });
```

`ChangeDetectorRef` is imported from `@angular/core`

You can read more about `ChangeDetectorRef` [Here](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html)

Comment: why to do that instead of find  a reason?

Comment: I'm going off experience, I spent many days trying to find the issue into why my UI would not update after making a call to a `Firebase` database, even asked on SO but with no avail.  This ended in using either `ChangeDetectorRef` or `NgZone`. The OP can always try what I have suggested and if it works then we can dig a little deeper, no harm in trying I guess.